# compile gcc 4.8.2 as static executable

Tags: c++, gcc

I've downloaded gcc4.8.2 and the related packages. It is configured as follows before make && make install:

```
configure --prefix=${HOME}/gcc --with-gmp=${HOME}/gcc --with-mpfr=${HOME}/gcc --with-mpc=${HOME}/gcc --disable-multilib
```

All is good and fine until I run the new g++:

```
${HOME}/gcc/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/cc1plus: error while loading shared libraries: libmpc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I can specify the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include where mpc library is, but I'd like to compile these into g++ or gcc as static.  But I didn't see such option in the 'configure' script.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if gcc can be build as a static executable. But you should not need to change `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `ld.so.conf`, your custom build version of `gcc` must work straight away.

Check where mpc and friends shared libraries where installed into. It can be either `${PREFIX}/lib` or `${PREFIX}/lib64`.

I normally build the prerequisite libraries passing `--prefix=${PREFIX} --libdir=${PREFIX}/lib64` to `configure`.

And then configure gcc with:

```
libs := gmp mpfr mpc cloog isl binutils
gcc_libs_configure := $(patsubst %,--with-%-include=${PREFIX}/include,${libs}) $(patsubst %,--with-%-lib=${PREFIX}/lib64,${libs})

configure.gcc : install.isl install.gmp install.mpc install.mpfr install.cloog install.binutils
    cd gcc-${gcc_version}-obj && ../gcc-${gcc_version}-src/configure --prefix=${PREFIX} --program-suffix=${suffix.gcc.${gcc_version}} ${gcc_libs_configure} --disable-libunwind-exceptions --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-checking=release --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --enable-gold=default --enable-libstdcxx-time --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --disable-libgcj
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I specify the prefix and the related infra libraries under ${HOME}/gcc as in the included command line in the question.  We have gcc 4.4.6 and it's related in /usr/lib64.  I want to keep a separate version to test.  I supposed if I can make changes to the Makefile like you specified, I could make those lib link static to g++ as .a.